# SOLVED: Can't run Upgrade script 4.7.21 (Drupal6) due to unknown column = civicrm_custom_group.is_public

Tags: upgrade, drupal-6, 4.7.21

After installing the 4.7.21 upgrade my D6 site shows as upgraded and Civi appears to run correctly. However when I run the upgrade script I get error: `Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: no such field`""

If I delve into the error I find:
`[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'civicrm_custom_group.is_public' in 'field list']&quot;]`

Can anyone guide me how to fix this?

Comment: That sounds familiar - do you have views enabled? Are you using drush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have had to create this field in the db in several sites we have upgraded. Not sure why the upgrade script is failing to do this correctly

Fuzion have provided a [patch](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20318) for this to avoid the problem for future folks doing upgrades

Comment: Thanks Pete. I tried the patch but still wasn't successful. But fortunately I saw in the related comments stream a suggestion that the problem was related to Civi/Webform/Views/CTools so I disabled those and re-ran the upgrade. It ran perfectly.

Comment: Davy - thanks for the input on this. Not finding the discuss re CTools etc. Canyou pls point to it? I looked at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20623 and https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20507 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10028

Comment: Pete: Via https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20318 then Subtasks to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20502.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: For good measure here is a repeat of the above comment.

I was able to successfully install the upgrade to 4.7.21 on Drupal 6 after applying the patch mentioned above, and after disabling Views, CTools and Webform (and all related/dependant modules).

The upgrade then ran smoothly without any problems.